# How can i number subsections. I do want them in form like 2.0.1. I want them in form like 2.1?

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Chapter 2}

  \chapter{\LARGE Introduction.}    

\subsection{How are you}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just don't use subsections, but sections: `\section{bla}`.